# Can't connect firebase functions with google cloud sql

Tags: sql-server-2005, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I'm hosting a sql instance on google cloud sql. Firebase functions worked with this instance flawlessly.
Now it stopped working out of nowhere and I can't seem to get any error.

Code:

```
 const mssql = require('mssql');
 const settings = require('../settings.js');
    const pool = await mssql.connect(settings.sqlConfig);
    const query = `EXEC spUserDelete @userAuthUid='${userAuthUid}', @value=${value}`
    const queryRes = await pool.request().query(query)
```

It never returns queryRes and instead I always get Timeout error.

Comment: Are you *really* using SQL Server 2005 in the cloud? SQL Server 2005 went out of support a *long* time ago.

Comment: @Larnu It looks this was because the database was crashing. I had a TRANSACTION that didn't have the COMMIT command at the end of it. Whenever I called this method, the database would crash (which my understanding for the system not able to connect to it out of nowhere), then it will restart working again after like 2 hours.